# Paypal - when is the most appropriate time to save an order into the database

Tags: django, database, paypal, cart

I have been questioning when is the most appropriate moment to
save the order to the database, so everything works the best possible.

I created my own shopping cart with Django, working well!




**In theory I have these options to save the order in the database:**

> **1) before client goes to paypal**

The client may not finish the payment and I will have an obsolete order in my database

> **2) when the client is in paypal**

Ideally I would store the order when the client pays

> **3) after the client returns from paypal**

The client may think the payment was already processed, and decides to close the window without returning to the store. I receive the payment, but I can't notify the client with the custom email

I implemented option 1) but I'm not completely happy about this, I want to know the opinion someone with experience

Comment: Order and payment are two separate business events and should be treated as such. From the accounting, financial and legal point of view the only right choice is option 1. Now, we can go into debate if it's indeed the only right choice, but confirmation of an order (or purchase) has certain legal ramification - you now have a contractual agreement with the customer and his obligation from that point on is of course the payment, yours is delivery of ordered services or products.

Comment: You can simplify the process by saying that payment is the actual order confirmation, but this doesn't negate the fact that these are two business events.

Comment: @Borut Thank you for sharing your perspective. I'm glad I took option 1) although the inconvenience remains. A table was generated in the database, called PayPal IPNs , I mostly tried paypal sandbox, and all the payments I have there have the flag unchecked. Maybe the flag gets checked when the payment is confirmed? Do you know exactly what is the flag about?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. I'm not familiar with PayPal IPN.